# Combine multiple polygons into a single one (with holes)

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas, shapely

I have the following GeoDataFrame with multiple polygons which represents a single area (`raster_val = 1.0`) with holes in the middle (`raster_val = NaN`):

```
                                       geometry           raster_val
0   POLYGON ((8.77500 47.70000, 8.77500 47.67500, ...         NaN
1   POLYGON ((8.90000 47.40000, 8.90000 47.30000, ...         NaN
...
9   POLYGON ((6.12500 46.27500, 6.12500 46.25000, ...         1.0
10  POLYGON ((8.57500 47.80000, 8.57500 47.77500, ...         1.0
11  POLYGON ((8.90000 45.85000, 8.90000 45.82500, ...         1.0
```

I would like to combine polygons corresponding to `raster_val = 1.0` into a single Polygon/Multipolygon but preserving the holes indicated by the polygons with `raster_val = NaN`.

I've already tried geopandas `dissolve()` method:

```py
polygons = polygons.dissolve(by='raster_val')
```

This combines `raster_val = 1.0` polygons but it ignores all `raster_val = NaN` polygons so the combined multipolygon doesn't have any holes. Do you have any suggestions on how to include those `NaN` holes?

Comment: Cant you use [Difference](https://geopandas.org/set_operations.html) after your dissolve with a dataframe of `raster_val is NaN` as "erase" features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps shapely's [unary_union](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#shapely.ops.unary_union) will help, where `df` is your GeoDataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd
from shapely.ops import unary_union

hole_indx = pd.isna(df.raster_val)

holes = unary_union(df.loc[hole_indx, 'geometry'])
polys = unary_union(df.loc[~hole_indx, 'geometry'])

polys_and_holes = polys.difference(holes)
```